# Sql array only showing first result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to put the results in variables seperately but for that I will need to be able to call them separate. Right now I have this query that retrieves 6 results (tested with mysqli_num_rows).
But when I print it, it will only shows the first row from my 6 results.

```
$result =  mysqli_query ($con, $query) or die("FOUT: " . mysqli_error($con));

echo "<p>mysqli_num_rows($result)</p>";

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Results from

```
print_r($row) = 

Array ( [0] => Iran [1] => 28 )
```

Comment: What does the query look like? **fetch_row** not **fetch_rows**

Comment: Hi, the query is: $query ="SELECT * FROM WKaverage WHERE Average > 27.8"; but that works fine on mySQL.

Comment: You will need to call `mysqli_fetch_row()` for each single row.

Comment: wheres the rest of your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all rows you will need to do something like:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
// $rows will now contain all rows in the result set
```

Comment: Thanks man, you are right! Will give you 'accept answer' in 8!

Comment: is `$rows` init required? (less code better code, easy to read code better code)

Comment: @Kyslik - no that won't be needed.

Comment: @Kyslik - Although I would strongly recommend that you initialize the array as it makes the code clearer and also shows what data `$rows` is meant to hold. Also, I don't agree that `less code always means easier to read and better code`

Comment: @KristerAndersson I asked that question in educational way, I know that in PHP you do not have to initialise variables. Some prefer less code some prefer more readable code. Thanks tho ;), MisterAnderson! good nick.

Answer (score 1):

Your function, mysqli_fetch_row(), only returns a single row result:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Try looping through like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) {
    // Do something
}
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: yes and no. ALL of the fetch functions return a single row. You need to fetch in a loop.

Comment: This will also just return a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use while

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
print_r($row);
//do more stuff...
}
```

You can use fetch_assoc instead of fetch_row to have logical array keys

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$result =  mysqli_query ($con, $query) or die("FOUT: " . mysqli_error($con));

echo "<p>mysqli_num_rows($result)</p>";

$rows = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

do
{
   $rows[] = $row;

}while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))

mysqli_free_result($result);
```